# не компилируется скрипт php в Geany 2

Tags: php

Помогите настроить Geany, чтоб он компилировал скрипт PHP. В начале при запуске появлялась командная строка с сообщением, что php не является внутренней или внешней программой, добавил путь к папке с php.exe в переменных средах, но теперь при запуске выскакивает сообщение "php startup: unable to load dynamic library \xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_mysql.dll - не найден указанный модуль." Видимо этих модулей он не может найти, но браузер при этом нормально обрабатывает скрипт, что же еще добавить в настройки Geany, чтоб он тоже обрабатывал скрипт php?

Comment: PHP не компилируется, это интерпретируемый язык. Напишите, пожалуйста, какого эффекта вы хотите добиться.

Comment: эффекта, чтоб в Geany выполнил скрипт php. Эта программа умеет это делать.  Но я не могу понять как ее правильно настроить на php.

Comment: Очевидно, в php.ini неправильно указан путь к `php_pdo_mysql.dll`. Надо его найти и прописать верный путь.

Comment: Но я не пойму, браузер же правильно работает и php отображает. просто не хочу каждый раз его запускать во время изучения php. если б неправильно был указан путь, то и браузер бы не отображал бы корректно. или его надо как то настроить именно под Geany  дополнительно?

Comment: Сервер, судя по всему, запускает другой интерпретатор с другой конфигурацией.